# waitForSelector with Puppeteer not responding only in headless mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am having a strange issue with puppeteer, I have the following code:

```
try {
    await Promise.all([
        page.waitForSelector(HomeSelector.profileButton),
        cursor.click(HomeSelector.profileButton),
        page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
    ]);
    // Never responds in headless mode
    await page.waitForSelector(ProfileSelector.nameField);


    resolve();
} catch(error) {
    reject(error); 
}
```

When I run puppeteer with `headless: false` it successfully waits for the selector `nameField` however with `headless: true` I just get the timeout error `TimeoutError: waiting for selector` .

I have tried changing the waitForNavigation parameter and that doesn't make a difference, I have also taken a screenshot of the website to confirm the elements are there.

Has anyone else faced this issue before? Any ideas how to go around fixing it?

Comment: I had the same kind of issue yesterday. It looks like Puppeteer doesn't render pages exactly the same way in headless and headful mode. Bug?

Comment: it is a very page specific question, can you share the url you are visiting with pptr? usually the answer is either some headless browser detection on the site or related to A/B tests on the UI (so you can land on the same page with different selector names).

Comment: Why aren't you waiting for `page.waitForSelector(HomeSelector.profileButton)` before clicking, `cursor.click(HomeSelector.profileButton)`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that you have some race condition between `page.waitForSelector(HomeSelector.profileButton)` and `cursor.click()`. Try to await the `page.waitForSelector(HomeSelector.profileButton)` first:

```js
try {
    await page.waitForSelector(HomeSelector.profileButton);
    await Promise.all([
        cursor.click(HomeSelector.profileButton),
        page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
    ]);
    await page.waitForSelector(ProfileSelector.nameField);

    resolve();
} catch(error) {
    reject(error); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to add the userAgent when creating the new context, I did this because when checking if the content of the page was being accessed with a screenshot `await page.screenshot({ path: "screenshot.png" });` immediately after performing the `await page.goto(url);`

```
await page.goto(url);
await page.screenshot({ path: "screenshot.png" });
await page.waitForSelector("#user-rut");
```

This helps me realize that I was getting a 403 forbidden nginx error. Apparently running `headless: true` the puppeteer deals with it with another type of agent.

The solution for me was to specify the userAgent to be able to load the page correctly and avoid the error that was getting `time out Error: page.waitForSelector waiting for selector to be visible`

```
const context = await browser.newContext({
    userAgent:
      "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36",
  });
```